# How to use a SQL Function with INNER JOIN in MySQL?

Tags: mysql, sql, function, join, inner-join

I have a function "fnc_FindIssueId" which accepts an object id and return its assigned issue Id.

When I call the function using pure select statements, it works fine:

```
select fnc_FindIssueId(150083); // returns 1 as issueId for objectId of 150083
select fnc_FindIssueId(150072); // returns 2 as issueId for objectId of 150072
```

But when I use it within an Inner Join, it goes into a never-ending loop:

```
select so.id, si.id
from smart_objects as so 
       LEFT OUTER join smart_issues as si 
        on si.id = fnc_FindIssueId(so.id)
where so.id in (150083, 150072);
```

What's the reason and how to resolve it?

Comment: Your second example is an **OUTER** join, not an *INNER* join.

Answer (score 1):

It does not perform *never-ending* loop.

The reason for that is because the server performs `FULL TABLE SCAN` which is very slow. This condition `si.id = fnc_FindIssueId(so.id)` doesn't use an index even if you have define one on `si.id` and `so.id`.

The best ways you can do are:

- to alter the table `smart_objects`
- another column for the `assigned issue Id`
- define an index on the new column

Comment: The logic to find the issue id is complex and depends on some other scenarios, that's why a separate function has been created. I can't change the design, please answer the question if you can, thanks.

Comment: Why does it perform a Full Table Scan?! I've added filters in the WHERE clause to limit them? It should apply the filter then the join, similar to SQL Server!

Comment: That's the best answer I can tell. Maybe others can. I can't help you optimize the query because you are joining against the result of  a function.

Comment: [How to Avoid Table Scans?](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/how-to-avoid-table-scan.html) and [Full table scan vs full index scan performance](http://www.mysqlperformanceblog.com/2012/11/23/full-table-scan-vs-full-index-scan-performance/)

Comment: how to force it to use the primary key index?

Answer (score 0):

The workaround was to create a new view with ObjectId and IssueId columns then calling that function from within that view! but it has become very slow now.

```
CREATE ALGORITHM=UNDEFINED DEFINER=`mysql`@`%` SQL SECURITY DEFINER VIEW `vw_smart_objectissue` AS select `so`.`id` AS `objectid`,`fnc_FindIssueId`(`so`.`id`) AS `issueid` from `smart_objects` `so` order by `so`.`id`$$
```